# How to limit zoom level and viewable areas in Google Maps?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Is it possible to do this?
I only want the users of the application to see a certain part of the Google Maps. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It's paternalism against the user.

Comment: @yunzen - I am making an application that only covers my city. The users should be limited of viewing other places.

Comment: @jetpro I see. But it's defined paternalism. Most users won't zoom out, and the ones that do will have a sound reason for that.

Comment: @yunzen - Yes, sir. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are events defined in the google maps API

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events

Comment: I've seen this before, but can I how can I use this for android programming?